"this device can't connect cloud pcs"
I'm a newbie admin. I restarted the cloud pc hitting the restart button while the session was active.
Now we can't connect to the environment from anywhere, including web.
The error reads:

This device can't connect cloud pcs. ask your admin to install any required apps on this device or use another device connect to your cloud PC

I have full access to everything. We don't have any conditional access set up. Restoring to a previous point didn't help. Device is compliant. Connectivity status is available.
